# French text in vb script

Tags: character-encoding, vbscript

HI I need to include a french text in vb script with special characters - REJETÉE.
When I add text, it appears as REJETÃ‰E.  How do I include the following? 
I can use either : É or É. but it shows exceptions.

Comment: Using VBScript for both a message box and the FileSystemObject TextStream, I get accents output properly. Can you include some code?

Answer (score 0):

Visual basic in itself does only support ASCII characters. The 'É' is an ANSI character, thus unsupported.
If you are writing to a text file, you may want to print the direct ANSI value of the character. If you now use a text editor that uses ANSI encoding, you will see the 'É' correctly.

Also, maybe the following will work as a debug output, you will have to try thou:

```
Debug.Print chr$(200)
```

You should get the 'È' character when writing the value 200. As I said, i don't know if this works in the debug printer, but when writing to text files it will work.